# What is the name of this potted plant with large, dark green, waxy-looking leaves?

Tags: identification, containers, succulents, ficus

I have bought it from an old lady that said it is a rubber tree. It doesn't look like a rubber plant from what I've seen on Google so far. Can you tell me what it is?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Peperomia pictures](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwierPCD_tjQAhUC52MKHYL8DGgQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.houseplant411.com%2Fhouseplant%2Fpeperomia-how-to-grow-care-tips&psig=AFQjCNGRrjyl2S92ruk10a4ksmdmhymCaA&ust=1480887508182008)

Good job guys, absolutely Peperomia!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [Rubber Tree plant](https://www.google.com/search?q=rubber%20tree%20plant&tbm=isch) aka Rubber Fig aka Ficus Elastica

Comment: Are you sure? No woody stem, could peperomia?

Comment: Well, it looks like Peperomia obtusifolia. Thank you.

Comment: Tis *Peperomia*. *Ficus elastica* has distinctive pointy shoots, often pink or purple tinged.

Comment: you guys are correct